# Why use defer lock with unique lock

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, c++14, raii, locks

Why use defer lock?
What is with taking ownership first then locking?
Isn't taking ownership and locking kinda same.
What if we took ownership using unique lock of a mutex and not locking, could it still be prone to race conditions?

```
    void fun1(std::mutex &m){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mlock(m);
        //multiple lines
    }

    void fun2(std::mutex &m){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex,std::defer_lock> mlock(m);
        //multiple lines
        mlock.lock();
        //multiple lines
    }
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag has an example

Answer (score 1):

> What if we took ownership...?

This does *not* "take ownership" of the mutex `m`:

```c++
std::unique_lock<std::mutex,std::defer_lock> mlock(m);
```

In effect, it says, I want to construct this [RAII object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), `mlock` now, but I am not going to lock `m` (i.e., "take ownership of `m`") until later.

> Could it still be prone to race conditions?

Absolutely. Yes.

```c++
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex,std::defer_lock> mlock(m);
    // Here, we still are prone to race conditions because m is not locked.
    ...
    std::lock(m);
    // Now, it's safe to use whatever data m protects.
    ...
}
// And here, m is guaranteed to be unlocked again.
...
```

---

**Response to comment, below**

> Any use cases for using defer lock?

Only use case I can think of* is similar to what's shown on the [cppreference web page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag) to which @Mat referred you.

1. You want to lock *two or more* mutexes, **and**
2. You want to control the order in which the mutexes are locked so that you can avoid deadlock, **and**
3. You want to use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) to ensure that there's no way for a thread to leave the block without unlocking all of the mutexes.

So, you write something like this:

```c++
{
    // Create RAII objects. `defer_lock` means, "Just create the objects,
    //  but don't actually lock the mutexes. I solemnly swear that
    //  that _I_ will lock them before this story ends."
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex, std::defer_lock> ulk_A(mutex_A);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex, std::defer_lock> ulk_B(mutex_B);

    // lock both mutexes
    if (...Deadlock avoidance requires A to be locked first...) {
        std::lock(mutex_A);
        std::lock(mutex_B);
    }
    else {
        std::lock(mutex_B);
        std::lock(mutex_A);
    }
    // _Now_ it's safe to access any shared data that are protected by
    // mutex_A or mutex_B.
    ...
}
// Can't leave the block without both mutexes being unlocked again.
```

---

* Maybe there's other uses. Just because  *I* can't imagine something doesn't mean it's not out there waiting for somebody else to imagine it.

Comment: Any use cases for using defer lock?